# Selenium server unable to connect to host, no display specified - OLD:failed to start new browser session

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, centos6

I'm using Selenium server (2.39.0) on centOs server 6.5 (redhat)
developing tests in PHP, using phpUnit (i installed phpunit by pear as well)

but everytime i get this error:

```
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': 
Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException:
Error while launching browser
Caused by
RuntimeException: 
Invalid response while accessing the Selenium Server at 'http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/': 
Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException:
Error while launching browser
```

this is the test that i'm trying to execute:

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
   function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser("*firefox");
    $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.google.com/");
  }

  function testMyTestCase()
  {
    $this->open("/");
    $this->type("q", "selenium rc");
    $this->click("btnG");
    $this->waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    $this->assertTrue($this->isTextPresent("Results * for selenium rc"));
  }
}
?>
```

i'm trying also to run the script using :

```
phpunit --configuration conf.xml example.php
```

where in conf.xml i've got:

```
<browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox" host="IPHOST" port="4444" timeout="30000" />
```

but i receive the same error

and the door 4444 is free:

```
netstat -anp | grep 4444
```

gives:

```
tcp        0      0 :::4444                     :::*                        LISTEN
```

what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

@sircapsalot: do you mean to change the script?

anyway i don't know if i'm going to the right direction but i changed something:
first of all the script is different:

```
<?php
class Example extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
  protected function setUp()
  {
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
  }

  public function testTitle()
  {
    $this->url('http://www.example.com/');
    $this->assertEquals('Example WWW page', $this->title());
  }
}
?>
```

and i installed Xvfb 
so now i don't have the error that selenium has failed to start new browser session,
but i'm having another error

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: 
Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000ms. 
Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
```

and i already tried with:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
```

and:

```
export DISPLAY=:99
```

Comment: for starters, you could go to Selenium WebDriver instead of WebDriverBackedSelenium

Comment: Do you have Firefox on your server? Does it work there?

Comment: @rNix, yes firefox is working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've fixed the "no display specified" error, the mistake was that selenium server was already running when i was starting Xvfb,
so this are the steps (after Xvfb and selenium installation):

- run Xvfb ( Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 & )
- export display ( export DISPLAY=:99 )
- run selenium ( java -jar selenium-server-standalone-versionNumber.jar )
- run script ( phpunit namefile.php )

if selenium is already running you can stop it by:

```
localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
```

now the script works